# mvc : Want to use one property in the object and not all of it

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a method that I only use in one property where I upload photos so I only use the Photo property
I don't want to put the object as a parameter but a string that will be a replacement for the object and overwrite the Photo or in another way when using a Dto that fails to do gets null.

It's a function that works for me but I use the whole object as a parameter when I only use the PHOTO URL:

```
public async Task<string> UploadPhotos(IFormFile file, Product product)
        {
            string wwwPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
            var path = Path.Combine(wwwPath, "images", file.FileName);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            return product.PhotoUrl = file.FileName;
        }
```

What I tried to do:

```
public async Task<string> UploadPhotos(IFormFile file, string photoUrl)
        {

            Product product = new()
            {
                PhotoUrl = photoUrl
            };

            string wwwPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
            var path = Path.Combine(wwwPath, "images", file.FileName);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            return product.PhotoUrl = file.FileName;
        }
```

It doesn't work for me when I try to upload it doesn't show me the picture

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromForm] ProductViewModel model)
    {

        ModelState.Clear();

        await _photoService.UploadPhotos(model.Photo,model.PhotoUrl);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _productRepository.AddProduct(model.Product!);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View();
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
  public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; } = null!;
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

View:

```
@model Solid_Project.Models.ProductViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddProduct";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<article>

    <section>

        <form asp-action="AddProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Product!.Name"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Product!.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" style="width:30%">
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Product!.Name" class="validation"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Product!.Description"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Product!.Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description" style="width:30%">
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Product!.Description" class="validation"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Product!.CategoryId"></label>
                <div>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.Product!.CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Category" style="width:30%" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-design"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></select>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Product!.CategoryId" class="validation"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Photo"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.Photo" accept="image/*" class="form-control" style="width:30%" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Photo" class="validation"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>


    </section>

</article>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Mor levi, why you pass the `model.PhotoUrl` to the method? From your form, you can see you never set such input, so it always null, but any way it should not influence the result, because you can see your `UploadPhotos` is used to upload the file, the return data is useless for your main method.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you were trying to say and if you could download it for me in the form of a code
@Rena